# Get details from plist file with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

Here is my problem.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the "Details" key in the same level as the "Name" key once search for a specific name key. Maybe I'm missing something?

I know you can get "Details" via `[dict objectForKey:@"Details"]` but I'm not sure how to get the one on the same levels as the one that was searched for.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)ScoringButtonView:(id)sender {
    ScoringViewController *svController = [[ScoringViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScoringView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];

    UIButton *scoringButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"Scoring is %@ ", scoringButton.currentTitle);
    svController.ScoringName = scoringButton.currentTitle;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scoring" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in plistData) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:scoringButton.currentTitle]) {
            NSLog(@"Scoring ==  %@ ", scoringButton.currentTitle);
//            svController.ScoringInfo = 
        }
    }
```

plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Standard</string>
            <key>Details</key>
            <string>dagsdfgds</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Advanced</string>
            <key>Details</key>
            <string>gfdsgdfsgdsfg</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Comment: If you get the name with `[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]`, how would you get the details?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You already know how to access the `@"Name"` key. Getting the `@"Details"` key is exactly the same.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, correct. I'm just not sure how to get the "Details" one on the same level as the "Name" one I searched for.

Comment: It's exactly the same as getting the Name key.

Comment: `svController.ScoringInfo = [dict objectForKey:@"Details"]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the confusion is. You already know how to get the value for the `Name` key. Getting the value for the `Details` key is the same:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in plistData) {
    if ([dict[@"Name"] isEqualToString:scoringButton.currentTitle]) {
        NSString *details = dict[@"Details"];
    }
}
```

Note how I used modern Objective-C syntax instead of the old style use of `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

**//This method should work fine**

**//Enumeration method is better than for loop**

```
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“LanguageList” ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
    NSError *error =  nil;
    NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];


   [dict[@"result"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull objList, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            NSLog(@“Values %@”,obj);
            *stop = YES;

        }
    }];
```